# Trying to Build a Sandwich Making Simulator

Tags: python

First time using Stackoverflow.

I'm a total noob with **Python** so I need a little help. I'm trying to make a choice based text adventure game and in the middle of it is going to be a sandwich making simulator *(don't ask how my mind works)* and I need a little help.

```
def sandwich():
print("You see bread, meat, cheese and mayo.")
while True:
    try:
        print(" 1. Bread \n 2. Meat \n 3. Cheese \n 4. Mayo")
        print ("Select the ingredients based on number. Which would you like to grab?")
        response = set(int(input("Select ingredients: ").strip))
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter an integer!")
```

I only have four choices to keep it simple so I can build from there. Basically I want to make the program check for user integer input and depending on that input give feedback on the sandwich that's created.

for example:

```
if response == "1234":
  print("Wow that's an amazing sandwich")
```

But I want the program to be able to be smart enough to do this regardless of the order that is given. So if someone puts in "4321" instead of "1234", it can give the same result. Currently I'm using set, int, and strip on line 7 (not sure if that's good or not) so that there can't be duplicates, and if spaces is added it should strip it away. It should also give an error if an integer is not entered.

I'm thinking of using *for loops* with *in*, but I have no idea where to begin or if that's even the right path.

Any points in the right direction would be appreciated!

Comment: you can check the output of your line : `set(int(input("Select ingredients: ").strip))` 
See what happens when you give it '1234' or '2341' or 'bla'

Comment: I think asking for user input with spaces or commas between entries would allow you to immediately dump their response into a list. Like `ingredients = input("Select ingredients: ").split()` Then you can use `ingredients.len()` to see how many ingredients they entered and provide output. Furthermore, once you have more than 9 ingredients it might be difficult to determine if their user input of `123` is "12" and "3" or "1", "2", and "3", but that problem disappears using lists to catch input.

Comment: `strip` is not necessary when converting to `int` - `int("    5   ")` gives `5`. And just convert the int back to a string and compare to the set `{'1', '2', '3', '4'}`

Comment: @ Kada: Thanks Kada. That's... probably a good idea and best practice lol. I probably should make sure line 7 would even work first before I do anything else.

Comment: @JNevill:  You might have a point there. I was thinking using only integers would make it more easy but it might just further complicate things yeah. I may go back to just asking for words. Thanks a bunch

Comment: @Tomerikoo: YOOO I appreciate that. I don't know why for some dumb reason I was thinking I needed strip. I figured something was off. Appreciate you! o/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is better to put the list of ingredients in a dictionary, so you can easily add or substract ingredients, and you have a relation between the number and the ingredient.

Strip is a function call, so it has to be written .strip()

Is better to not add the response directly to the set of ingredients, because you should validate it first.

You need a way to stop adding ingredients. If the user does not writes an integer, you could ask if he wants to stop adding ingredients.

```
sandwichIngredients = {1: "Bread", 2: "Meat", 3: "Cheese", 4: "Mayo"}
def sandwich():
    chosenIngredients=set()
    print("You see "+ ", ".join(sandwichIngredients.values())+".")
    while True:
        try:
            print(*[f"{number}. {ingredient}" for number, ingredient in sandwichIngredients.items()], sep="\n")
            print ("Select the ingredients based on number. Which would you like to grab?")
            response=int(input("Select ingredients: ").strip()) #strip is a function call, so it has to be written .strip()
            if response in chosenIngredients:
                print("You already have that ingredient.")
                continue
            elif response not in sandwichIngredients:
                print("That is not an ingredient.")
                continue
            else:
                chosenIngredients.add(response)
            if len(chosenIngredients)==len(sandwichIngredients):
                print("Wow that's an amazing sandwich.")
                break
        except ValueError:
            if input("That is not a number. Do you want to finish the sandwich? (y/n)").lower()=="y":
                break
            print("Please enter an integer!")
    #now you can print the ingredient names by using the dictionary
    print("your sandwich has the following ingredients: " + ", ".join([sandwichIngredients[i] for i in chosenIngredients]))

sandwich()
```

Comment: `strip` is not necessary when converting to int. `int("   5  ")` still gives `5`

Comment: @Colim: WOW You put a ton of work into this and I thank you so much for that. Far more than I thought anyone would! I appreciate you! I wanted to one up your comment but I don't have the reputation. I did give you a checkmark though!